# Tautological implication and monotony/monotonicity of Tarski condition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-explanation

I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the definition of an union set; the following is from the notes published by Prof David Makinson at LSE for a further logic course:

> Prove that from its definition that tautological implication satisfies monotony/monotonicity of Tarski condition (Whenever $A ⊨ \alpha$ then $A\cup B ⊨ \alpha$).
>
> Solution: Suppose $A ⊨ \alpha$; we want to show that $A\cup B \vDash \alpha$. Let $v$ be any valuation and suppose $v$ makes all formulae in $A\cup B$ true. Then it makes all formulae in $A$ true, so by the first supposition it makes $\alpha$ true.

$v(\forall x(x\in A\cup B))=T$ leads to $v(\forall x (x\in A))=T$ because $A\cup B=\forall x(x\in A \lor x\in B) $, therefore it means everything that is either a member of $A$ or $B$ is true. From that all formulae in A are true.

But this doesn't seem to make sense if I look at the definition: IF (and this is a BIG if) I am understanding correctly, all formulae in $A\cup B$ are still true under $v$ if $v(\forall x (x\in A))=T$ but $v(\forall x (x\in B))=F$, because of the inclusive disjunction in the definition of $A\cup B$. (In particular $x\in A\cup B$ still holds if $x\in A$ but $\lnot x\in B$)

But if so, 'All formulae in $A\cup B$ are true. Then it makes all formulae in $A$ true', if I replace the 2nd sentence with 'Then it makes all formulae in $B$ true', it doesn't make sense anymore because in the current truth assignment, we are assuming all formulae in A are true but all formulae in B are false.

I am sure it is my understanding of union set that went wrong (2nd paragraph); but I can't tell how. Could anyone tell me where I went wrong please?

Comment: It's from the notes of a course I attended earlier so I am not sure how to quote it. $v(\forall x(x\in A\cup B))=T$ just means every formulae in $A\cup B$ is true, so it's just a formulated way of saying the same thing; unless I am understanding what the solution said wrong?

Comment: And while I do respect your concern of plagiarism, I am not sure how this is the case here, as I am certainly not taking credit for it (otherwise I would have understood it), nor am I passing it on as an answer or anything...

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but in terms of meaning I honestly am not sure if there is a difference...both seems to mean the same thing, ie we are assigning a truth value $T$ to everything that is either in $A$ or $B$, the only difference seems to be that the latter is using $\alpha$ to denote the formulae in the union while the former uses $x$

Comment: Edited to credit Prof David Makinson at LSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The union $A\cup B$ is defined as $\{x|x\in A \vee x\in B\}$. So, $c\in A\cup B$ iff it is true that "$c\in A$ or $c\in B$."

For example, if $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{2,3,4,5\}$, then $A\cup B = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Using the definition, $2\in A\cup B$ because it is true that "$2\in A$ or $2\in B$" ... so are other elements of $A\cup B$.

For now, we make the numbers "represent" propositions. Suppose a valuation $v$ makes all formulae in $A∪B$ true. That is, $v(1)=T, v(2)=T,..., v(5)=T$.

With $A=\{1,2,3\}$, do we have $v(1)=T, v(2)=T$, and $v(3)=T$ ?

**Edit:**

Another example: Let $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{4,5\}$. Then, $A\cup B=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Now, suppose we have a valuation $v$ such that all formulae in $A$ are true but all formulae in $B$ are false. So we have $v(1)=v(2)=v(3)=T$ and $v(4)=v(5)=F$.

With $A\cup B=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, do we have $v(1)=v(2)=...=v(5)=T$ (or are all formulae in $A\cup B$ true)?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Yes it would seem that we do have $v(1)=v(2)=v(3)=T$. (Side question: am I right in saying that it makes no sense to say that that $v(A\cup B)=T$/a valuation makes $A\cup B$ true, because a set cannot be true or false, but only to say that $v$ makes ALL FORMULAE in $A\cup B$ true, since only formulae can take a truth value?)

Comment: But suppose we have a valuation st all formulae in $A$ are true but all formulae in $B$ are false (obviously your example would then not be applicable since $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive), would that make all formulae in $A\cup B$ true? I think this is where it confuses me the most because the definition of a union utilises a disjunction, which will be true as long as one disjunct is true. Just by looking at what has been said, it would seem that the answer is no/not all formulae in $A\cup B$ is true, but I am not 100% certain.

Comment: (1) *...but only to say that $v$ makes ALL FORMULAE in $A∪B$ true, since only formulae can take a truth value?* Yes. Take note that $v(A∪B)=T$ can be an abuse of notation...

Comment: (2) The disjunction utilized in the set union is just a criterion for an *element* to be a member of the set $A\cup B$. The valuation $v$ doesn't care on set operations – it only cares on a formula $p$, which it tells whether $p$ is $True$ or $False$.

Comment: (3) See my edit on my answer.

Comment: Yes from the way you explained the disjunction operator I now get it; no in the 2nd example not all formulae in $A\cup B$ are true. I study on my own without a teacher so I am really grateful for you help; thank you so much!